# Local Notifications on Adobe Air

Tags: ios, air, adobe, apple-push-notifications

In AIR 3.4, Adobe introduced support of Push Notifications. But how i can do more simple local notifications in AIR? Everywhere it is written only about Push Notifications.

Comment: What do you mean with local notifications? Like alerts from within the application or alerts to the OS from a suspended application?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK local notifications such as alerts, are still not supported in Air for iOS. You need to use a native extension for that.

Such as this one:

http://labs.distriqt.com/native-extensions#local-notifications